# How to access live webcam remotely on iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, ios, webcam, live-streaming

I want to access live streaming from a webcam on my iPhone and i am wondering how to do this. Scenario is that i am using webcam on my laptop and my laptop and my iPhone are connected with a same network. Now webcam of my laptop is on, is there any way to access the streaming of my laptop webcam?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ffmpeg library (libavcodec) on iPhone and GStreamer on your laptop.

start udp streaming on laptop using GStreamer, play video on iPhone using FFMpeg library from UDP stream.